# How to differenciate the data when doing a UNION on 2 SELECTS?

Tags: mysql, select, union

If I have the following two tables :

### Employes

Bob
Gina
John

### Customers

Sandra
Pete
Mom

I will do a UNION for having :

### Everyone

Bob
Gina
John
Sandra
Pete
Mom

The question is :
In  my result, how can I creat a dumn column of differenciate the data from my tables ?

### Everyone

Bob (Emp)
Gina (Emp)
John (Emp
Sandra (Cus)
Pete (Cus)
Mom (Cus)

I want to know from with table the entry is from withouth adding a new column in the database...

```
SELECT Employes.name
FROM Employes
UNION
SELECT Customers.name
FROM Customers;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just introduce a constant addition to the column (rather than the table):

```
SELECT name || ' (Emp)' as name FROM Employees
UNION
SELECT name || ' (Cus)' as name FROM Customers;
```

and spell "Employees" correctly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add the "column" in your select statement.

```
SELECT Employes.name, '(Emp)' as PersonType
FROM Employes
UNION
SELECT Customers.name, '(Cus)' as PersonType
FROM Customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Employee' AS table
       Employes.name 
  FROM Employes 
UNION 
SELECT 'Customer' AS table
       Customers.name 
  FROM Customers;
```

or

```
SELECT Employes.name + ' (Emp)'
FROM Employes 
UNION 
SELECT Customers.name + ' (Cus)'
FROM Customers;
```